# Adding an ImageView to a parent Activity from a class

Tags: android, position, imageview, parent

I would like to create a flexible class that I can drop into any project I create.  This class will produce an image (ultimately, an image from a server) and place it on the calling Activity's view.

The idea is: an Activity creates an instance of this class, and when I want to display the image, I call the class's "show" method, passing x and y coordinates, along with width and height, and a default image name to use if it can't load one from a server.

I am having difficulty getting the ImageView I create to position properly in the parent Activity.  I've tried a number of different approaches, but here's what I've got for the class thus far:

```
public class ImageProducer 
{   
        //parent activity
        Activity parentActivity;

    public void show(int x, int y, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, String defaultImage)
    {
        Resources r = parentActivity.getResources();
        String packageName = parentActivity.getPackageName();
        String imagePath = packageName + ":drawable/" + defaultImage;
        int rID = r.getIdentifier(imagePath,null,null);
        ImageView v = new ImageView(parentActivity.getBaseContext());
        v.setImageResource(rID);
        v.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight, x, y);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        parentActivity.addContentView(v, lp);
    }

    public ImageProducer(Activity a)
    {
        parentActivity = a;

    }
}
```

The image appears in the parent Activity, but always positions itself in the upper-left.

Any ideas on how to position it from within my class?  The tricky part is that the parent Activity doesn't have a a set layout.

Thanks very much

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and it not recommended to use.

Comment: Thanks, Emil.  I know that AbsoluteLayout is deprecated; I ended up trying that as a last-ditch effort to specify where the ImageView should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

There are one or 2 ways I can think of doing this.

You could ensure that the root layout of all your activities layouts is a `RelativeLayout` and then add your view to that with the necessary params to center it in the view. This means the layout is the the first child in the `RelativeLayout` and your image is added as the second child and so would appear on top of the first child.

or

You create your own layout manager by extending `ViewGroup`. You'll probably need to make some tweaks to it but essentially this is how the `ViewGroup` should look.

```
public class Article2 extends ViewGroup {

    private View layout;
    private ImageView theImage;
    private Context ctx;

public Article2(Context context,View layout) {
    super(context);
    ctx = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.addView(layout);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSpecSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSpecSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    for(int i = 0;i<this.getChildCount();i++){
        final View child = this.getChildAt(i);
        measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);   
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(widthSpecSize, heightSpecSize);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    layout.layout(left, top, right, bottom);

    if(theImage!= null){
        theImage.layout(right/2 - theImage.getMeasuredHeight()/2, bottom/2 -theImage.getMeasuredHeight()/2, right/2 + theImage.getMeasuredHeight()/2, bottom/2 + theImage.getMeasuredHeight()/2);
    }

}

public void startImage(String url){
    theImage = new ImageView(ctx);
    new GetImage(url).execute();
}

private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{
String url=null;
public GetImage(String url){
    this.url = url;
}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    if(url!=null&&url.length()>0){

        try {
            theImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean addView){
    if(addView){
            addView(theImage);
    }
}
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to add how to use the class above.

In `onCreate()` instead of setting the content view to a layout file like so

```
setContentView(R.layout.MyLayout);
```

instead do this

```
Article2 article2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyLayout, null);
    article2 = new Article2(this,v);
    setContentView(article2);
}
```

with this way those 5 lines above are all you need to put into each activity to get it to work

To show the image just call `parentActivity.article2.startImage(url)` and it'll place an image on top of the view you gave it in the center of the screen

One note, I didn't put anything in there to remove the image once it's been placed you probably just need to use `article2.removeViewAt(1)` but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Thank you, triggs.  I will mull over both your suggestions and see if they do what I need.

Comment: Did you mean `setContentView(article2);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here's what I ended up doing to get things working:  I added the ImageView to the parentActivity, after which I grabbed a pointer to the layout parameters.  The LayoutParams are FrameLayout, so I had to set the gravity, then specify the x and y values.  Here's what my code looks like:

```
    Resources r = parentActivity.getResources();
        String packageName = parentActivity.getPackageName();
        packageName+=":drawable/" + defaultImage;
        int rID = r.getIdentifier(packageName,null,null);
        ImageView v = new ImageView(parentActivity.getBaseContext());
        v.setImageResource(rID);

        parentActivity.addContentView(v, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width=w;
        lp.height=h;
        lp.gravity=Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        lp.leftMargin=x;
        lp.topMargin=y;
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        v.requestLayout();
```

Thanks again for all the suggestions!